# I need to get specific values from a node with HtmlAgilePack

Tags: c#, html, nodes, html-agility-pack

I need to extract some data from a page, of which the HTML is poorly named. The html looks something like the following:

```
<div class="container-entry">
    <h1 class="entry-heading">Aarakocra</h1>
    <div class="entry-metadata">
        <h2 class="entry-metadata-label">Armor Class: </h2>
        <h2 class="entry-metadata-label">12</h2>
    </div><div class="entry-metadata">
        <h2 class="entry-metadata-label">hit Points: </h2>
        <h2 class="entry-metalabel-content">13 (3d8)</h2></div>
```

In this example, I am trying to get the values "12" and "13 (3d8)"

So far I've tried this:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb website = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument pageMonsterStats = website.Load(websiteUrl + "/" + monsterName);
var monsterNode = pageMonsterStats.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='container-entry']");
Console.WriteLine(monster.Descendants("div").Where(node => node.Equals("Armor Class: ")).ToString());
```

I expected to get the index of the element which contains "Armor Class: ", which I would then use to get the value ("12") from the same element, but this returns "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because Where does return an IEnumerable. Try First, Last or concat your output into a string.

```
Console.WriteLine(monster.Descendants("div").First(node => node.Equals("Armor Class: ")).ToString());
```

In your case you may want to do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const string html = @"
<div class=""container-entry"">
  <h1 class=""entry-heading"">Aarakocra</h1>
  <div class=""entry-metadata"">
    <h2 class=""entry-metadata-label"">Armor Class: </h2>
    <h2 class=""entry-metadata-label"">12</h2>
  </div>
  <div class=""entry-metadata"">
    <h2 class=""entry-metadata-label"">hit Points: </h2>
    <h2 class=""entry-metalabel-content"">13 (3d8)</h2>
  </div>
</div>
";
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var monsterNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='container-entry']");
    var data = monsterNode.Descendants("div").Select(x => x.Descendants("h2")).SelectMany(x => x).Select(x => x.InnerText).ToArray();
    var armorClass = data[1];
    var hitPoints = data[3]; // if you want

    Console.WriteLine(armorClass); // output 12
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1MwaJ2)